# Trouble Creating Multiple Lines from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a line plot with multiple lines.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
UNIVERSITY YEAR RECORDS
BROWN 1995-01-01 100
BROWN 2000-01-01 1000
YALE 1995-01-01 500
YALE 2000-01-01 5000
```

The code I have been trying looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('stats_test.txt',delimiter='\t',index_col='UNIVERSITY',parse_dates=['YEAR'])
lines = df.plot.line(x='YEAR',y='RECORDS',label=df['UNIVERSITY'])
plt.show()
```

I don't know how to get a line for Brown and a line for Yale.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `YEAR` as the index and then use [Groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df.set_index('YEAR').groupby('UNIVERSITY')['RECORDS'].plot()
```

Output:

[image]